# How do I set up a single web server/nameserver to offer multiple domains to the same IP?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, centos, nameserver

I'm trying to set up an apache and DNS (bind) server on CentOS 5.6  I want to have 2 domains, test.kom, and d.dg.kom, pointing to a single IP, 172.25.2.1, which is the IP of the server.

D.dg.kom works great. test.kom does not. NSLookup results for test.kom are "*** Can't find test.kom: No answer"

/var/log/messages for named say "the working directory is not writable" and the 3 zone files say "loaded serial #####..." with no errors. There's also an error for a logging channel I tried to set up, but I'm pretty sure that's unrelated.

- Named.conf: 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1f6q.png
- dg.kom.zone: 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AzmQ.png
- test.kom.zone: 
  (imgur URL)  /Cxoyt.png
- Reverse
  lookup zone: 
  (imgur url)  /qEVjK.png

Comment: 1. Please don't post off-site image links. Include the *actual* configuration information in your question. 2. This question is not programming related and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry Greg. I only have SSH access, as the server is a VM off-site. It's difficult to copy text from the window. I'll do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

Your test.kom zone file is missing a trailing period for the hostname of the A record. Add that in, and it should work as expected. (Alternately, look up test.kom.test.kom right now, and you will likely get an answer.)